# Autogenerate excel borders and cell format when adding a new row

Tags: excel

I need a way how to set in my .xlsx file cell borders and cell number/percent/date/alignment format.
So, cells to be by default, by since I write a value into cell, it automatically apply borders and format to that cell.

Comment: Ok, with formats is everything ok, but I need a way to set that once a value exist in this range, in "x" cell, apply borders to that cell.

Comment: I would just use conditional formatting. If the conditional formatting rule is applied above and below where you are inserting a new row, that new row will automatically have the same formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend simply inserting a table (insert>table) after selecting your data. You can then apply your required formatting on the table, thus whenever a new row is added to the table, the table height will increase automatically which will incorporate the formatting in the new row

If this doesn't fit your use case then you will need to write a macro in the worksheet, maybe a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or a `Worksheet_Change` trigger which will be triggered whenever there is a change, post which you can write codes to format the cell.